# JavaFx: How to properly fire updateItem in a TableCell

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, listener

I have to implement a lot of custom TableCell which behavior relies on the model's change. I could manage to get somehow the expected result, but I think in many cases it was a workaround rather a really good solution. 
I have used bindings/listeners to achieve the expected result, but the problem I face is that I may add the listeners/bind the properties multiple times and it can create memory leaks.

Here is an example what I mean.

Controller:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TableView<Model> table;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Model, String> column;
    @FXML private Button change;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        column.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().text);
        column.setCellFactory(cell -> new ColoredTextCell());

        Model apple = new Model("Apple", "#8db600");

        table.getItems().add(apple);
        table.getItems().add(new Model("Banana", "#ffe135"));

        change.setOnAction(event -> apple.color.setValue("#ff0800"));

    }

    @Getter
    private class Model {
        StringProperty text;
        StringProperty color;

        private Model(String text, String color) {
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);
            this.color = new SimpleStringProperty(color);
        }
    }

    private class ColoredTextCell extends TableCell<Model, String> {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || getTableRow() == null || getTableRow().getItem() == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
                return;
            }
            Model model = (Model) getTableRow().getItem();
            Text text = new Text(item);
            text.setFill(Color.web(model.getColor().getValue()));

            // This way I add the listener evey item updateItem is called.
            model.getColor().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue != null) {
                    text.setFill(Color.web(newValue));
                } else {
                    text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                }
            });
            setGraphic(text);
        }
    }

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="stackoverflow.tabpane.Controller">
    <VBox>
        <Button fx:id="change" text="Change color"/>
        <TableView fx:id="table">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="column" prefWidth="200"/>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

Since the color property isn't directly observed by the cell the updateItem is not called if it changes, so I have to listen to somehow.
I would need that the `updateItem` to be triggered after the **color** is changed. This would result a single call to the content of the listener.

Is there any way to listen to another change of the model in the same cell, or call the update item somehow, so the change gets rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do it the other way around.

I would create a color property like this:

```
    ObjectBinding<Paint> colorProperty = Bindings.createObjectBinding(()->{
        String color = model.getColor().get();
        return Paint.valueOf(color==null?"BLACK":color);
    } , model.getColor());
```

Then I would bind the property like that:

```
text.fillProperty().bind(model.colorProperty);
```

It would be even simpler if you just had:

```
    SimpleObjectProperty<Paint> textColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<Paint>(Paint.valueOf("BLACK"));
```

and then in getter and setter of your model update such property.

Answer (score 3):

Using listeners and bindings won't cause any issues so long as you remember to remove them when they're no longer needed. To make it even safer, you should use weak listeners (bindings use weak listeners). As you want to change the cell's text's color based on a different property of the row's item, I think using a binding will be easier. Note that `TableCell` inherits from `Labeled` which means it has a `textFill` property; there's no need to create a `Text` node to change the color of the text.

Here's an example:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class ColoredTextCell extends TableCell<Model, String> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        /*
         * I was getting a NullPointerException without the "getTableRow() == null"
         * check. I find it strange that a TableCell's "updateItem" method would be
         * invoked before it was part of a TableRow... but the added null check seems
         * to solve the problem (at least when only having two items in the table and
         * no scrolling).
         */
        if (empty || item == null || getTableRow() == null) {
            setText(null);
            textFillProperty().unbind();
        } else {
            setText(item);

            Model rowItem = getTableRow().getItem();
            textFillProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                    () -> Color.valueOf(rowItem.getColor()),
                    rowItem.colorProperty()
            ));
        }
    }

}
```

The call to `textFillProperty().unbind()` will prevent a memory leak. And when binding a property the previous binding, if any, will be removed. If you're really paranoid you can call `unbind()` before `bind(...)` as well. And if you're really, *really* paranoid then you can store the `ObjectBinding` in a field and call [`dispose()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Binding.html#dispose()) when appropriate (and even null it out).

Comment: There is something I do not fully understand. `Bindings.createObjectBinding(..)` is scoped in the else block, and the javadoc says the bind uses a weak listener. Who holds the reference for such binding?

Comment: @minus The `ObjectBinding` itself is stored in a strong reference inside the `textFill` property. As the `TableCell` has a strong reference to that property the binding is strongly reachable. However, the listener that the binding adds to the `Observable` dependencies is weak, as is the listener that the property adds to the `ObservableValue` passed to `bind(...)`.

Comment: @minus Note that weak listeners are meant to prevent the _object that added the listener_ from being kept in memory just because the _object the listener was added to_ is strongly reachable.

Comment: First I didn't want to go for the binding's way because in my case it is more complicated than just setting the color, there are a few checks and I use `TextFlow` instead of `Text` which has many `Text`'s as children, but finally I managed to go for it and now its perfect ist is not called more than needed.  I think I will accept the minus's solution since he was the first one and basically its the same suggestion. Hope its ok for you ;)

Comment: @Sunflame Sure, no problem. Also, if your view starts to get decently complicated, consider moving it into its own class. Then set the `graphic` as an instance of that class. And note your example creates a new `Text` instance every time; consider caching the view objects to avoid creating and throwing away hundreds of them as the user scrolls.

Comment: Sure, I dont create a new instance every time in the `updateItem`, but I reuse it, at my example I just was hurry and didn't pay enough attention on it.

Comment: @Sunflame Thought I'd mention it just in case (might also help others who come along).